# How to change the path of an arrow in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

Basically I want the arrow which is going throught the node not going throught the node, my only solution was to shift the goal node 5mm down, but how can I achieve this without moving the node? How do I have to change the arrow?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata, backgrounds, positioning, fit,petri}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\title{Hausaufgabe 18, Potenzmengenkonstruktion}
\date{\today}

%\hspace{5mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten > = 1pt, > = {Stealth}]
        \node[state] (s0s3) {$ \{s_{0}, s_{3}\} $};
        \node (start) [left = of s0s3, xshift = 3mm] {};
        \node[state] (s3) [below right = of s0s3] {$ \{s_{3}\} $};
        \node[state] (nothing) [right = of s3] {$ \{\varnothing\} $};
        \node[state, accepting] (s1s3) [right = of s0s3, xshift = 1cm] {$ \{s_{1}, s_{3}\} $};
        \node[state, accepting] (s1s2s3) [above left = of s1s3] {$ \{s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}\} $};
        \node[state] (s4s5) [above right = of s1s3] {$ \{s_{4}, s_{5}\} $};
        
        \path[->] (start) edge (s0s3)
        (s0s3) edge node [above] {$ a $} (s1s3)
        edge [bend right = 15] node [right, yshift = 2mm] {$ b $} (s3)
        (s3) edge node [above] {$ b $} (nothing)
        edge [bend left = 25] node [left] {$ a $} (s1s3)
        (s1s3) edge [bend right = 45] node [left, yshift = -2mm] {$ a $} (s1s2s3)
        edge [bend left = 45] node [right, yshift = -2mm] {$ b $} (s4s5)
        (s1s2s3) edge [loop above] node [above] {$ a $} (s1s2s3)
        edge [bend left = 30] node [above] {$ b $} (s4s5)
        (s4s5) edge [bend left = 30] node [right] {$ a $} (nothing)
        edge [bend left = 120] node [right, yshift = -2mm] {$ b $} (s3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The b arrowq on the right, going from s4s5 to s3]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You should put `s3` below `s1;s3` and `EMPTY` on the right of `s3`.

Comment: Thank you @Mensch

Comment: @projetmbc unfortunately that just makes the arrow go straight throught {nothing}

Comment: Give us a MWE. This will help us to help you...

Comment: @projetmbc sorry, what is a MWE?

Comment: Just add `looseness=1.5` to the edge options for that arrow. Also, in the future, please always include complete code that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. It's kind of a pain for users to guess which packages, libraries and styles you're using so that we can improve your code. Please help us to help you.

Comment: @SandyG thank you that works, I will include that in the future, sorry for not doing that.

Comment: In the manual, all the possible ways to change that curve are documented in the section about the [`topaths` library](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#sec-74.3) (which always gets loaded). You can change distances, the looseness factor, the angles (absolute and relative).

Comment: Thank you @Qrrbrbirlbel I didn't read that part of the documentation, but I did now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `looseness` factor to the edge resolves the issue. The default is `looseness=1`. A value of 0 will produce a straight line.

```
edge [bend left = 120, looseness=1.5] node [right, yshift = -2mm] {$ b $} (s3);
```

[image]